# DB Query matching ids and sum data on columns

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the info i have on my tables, what i need is to create a report based on certain dates and make a sum of every stock movement of the same id

```
Table one                   Table Two
  Items                        Stocks
----------           ---------------------------
ID  - NAME           items_id  - altas - bajas - created_at

1     White             4          5       0         8/10/2016
2     Black             2          1       5         8/10/2016
3     Red               3          3       2         8/11/2016
4     Blue              4          1       4         8/11/2016
                        2          10      2         8/12/2016
```

So based on a customer choice of dates (on this case lets say it selects all the data available on the table), i need to group them by items_id and then SUM all altas, and all bajas for that items_id, having the following at the end:

```
items_id   altas  bajas  
  1         0      0
  2         11     7
  3         3      2
  4         6      4
```

Any help solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
Stock.select("sum(altas) as altas, sum(bajas) as bajas").group("item_id")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, only i had to add one extra thing on the select, item_id as item_id, otherwise it gave me no method errors when i try to print the name of the item, but it was a lot easier and faster than expected, thank you!